# Jquery drop down menu offset help

Tags: javascript, jquery, drop-down-menu

This is my third jquery script, and parts of this have been taken from other scripts. I'm trying to implement the following feature:

I've spent 4 hours trying to figure out how to get the submenu to display left if the browser window is too small. Currently it only works on large resolutions too. I found one script on here, but it only detected it on page load. This script used offset(), and this caused my marquee to fail on firefox. I'd like to avoid this if possible.

The menu is running here: http://www.mantisclan.com/beta/dropdown/

I'd like to use .addClass and .removeClass to set the left: position of the submenu.

Thanks for the help, I will learn from this.

Answer (score 0):

So it seems to work here: http://jsfiddle.net/JLUqH/2/. However I don't like this effect because it is quite impossible to control the menu, it pops up, collapses very fast.

Try changing the event from hover to click.

There are a lot of jQuery plugins that handle drop down menu creation for you: [**38 jQuery And CSS Drop Down Multi Level Menu Solutions**](http://www.1stwebdesigner.com/css/38-jquery-and-css-drop-down-multi-level-menu-solutions/)

Comment: Haha wow I actually had my first request working, I actually didn't test my last bit of code before coming here. Thanks for clarifying that xD. I only need help with detecting the window size, thanks!

Comment: document.body.clientHeight/Width gives you browser window height/width http://www.howtocreate.co.uk/tutorials/javascript/browserwindow